# Convert ODS to XLSX results in too many columns

Tags: excel, xls, libreoffice, odf

I've converted an ODF file to XLSX using LibreOffice. When I open the output file in Excel 2013 there are too many columns on each sheet. How do I fix this? The scrollbars are now kind of useless. Note that I can't just copy and paste to a new sheet since there are many interrelated sheets with complex formulas. Should I upload the file somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: You really haven't provided much to go on but look for custom number formatting or formulas that return empty strings that are defining a data area larger than what actually exists. Tap Ctrl+End in Excel to see what Excel thinks is the extents of the `.UsedRange`. You may have to go up/down/across to find the cell that actually holds a formula/value/format that is redefining the `.UserRange`.

Comment: It stops at column AME or column #1019. Clearing the contents of the cells up to that point has no effect. Clearing all conditional formatting also has no effect. If it were a formula, wouldn't the behavior also occur in the original LibreOffice file?

Comment: Do you mean the column width is too small?  If that's it, you can highlight all the affected columns, right-click on one of the gray column numbers, and select the "column width" option.

Comment: No. Jeeped is correct. But .UsedRange is read-only, so I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: You've tried clearing cell contents and conditional formatting, but not yet tried removing other custom formats?  In LibreOffice you can remove all custom formats by opening the Styles and Formatting window (Format->Styles and Formatting), selecting all cells (click the gray area between the column A label and the row 1 label), then double-click on the format named "Default" in the Styles and Formatting window.  In Excel, you would also select all cells, then on the Home tab click on "Clear" (near the right side of the tab in the subgroup "Editing") and choose "Clear Formats".

Comment: I tried both your suggestions in LibreOffice and Excel but they had no effect on the size of the scrollable region.